# Add a UIStepper to a settings bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistepper

I need to add a stepper to my settings bundle. Is there a way I can do it? I'm thinking I would create a table with a single cell and add the stepper to that. How do I do that in a settings bundle?

Comment: It's the plus and minus thing that allows you to increment or decrement a value.

Comment: If you don't need it for your UI, why in the world would you want to include it?  I don't get it.

Comment: I'm putting it in my settings bundle which you access through the settings app. Of course I need it for my UI. Not in my app but in the settings app, which contains a UI that users access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only things you can use in the settings bundle are these ones:

> **Text field** The text field type displays a title (optional) and an editable text field. You can use this type for preferences that
> require the user to specify a custom string value. The key for this
> type is PSTextFieldSpecifier.
>
> **Title** The title type displays a read-only string value. You can use this type to display read-only preference values. (If the
> preference contains cryptic or nonintuitive values, this type lets you
> map the possible values to custom strings.) The key for this type is
> PSTitleValueSpecifier.
>
> **Toggle switch** The toggle switch type displays an ON/OFF toggle button. You can use this type to configure a preference that can have
> only one of two values. Although you typically use this type to
> represent preferences containing Boolean values, you can also use it
> with preferences containing non-Boolean values. The key for this type
> is PSToggleSwitchSpecifier.
>
> **Slider** The slider type displays a slider control. You can use this type for a preference that represents a range of values. The value for
> this type is a real number whose minimum and maximum value you
> specify. The key for this type is PSSliderSpecifier.
>
> **Multivalue** The multivalue type lets the user select one value from a list of values. You can use this type for a preference that supports
> a set of mutually exclusive values. The values can be of any type. The
> key for this type is PSMultiValueSpecifier.

Find all the info here:

[Implementing an iOS Settings Bundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info. So I guess I'll just make a settings page in my app somewhere. Apple just makes it so hard to customize anything. They won't let you add custom settings which is really disappointing considering they advise you to put user controlled settings in the settings app rather than in the app itself. Oh well, thanks again.